# Time-based probability question

Tags: probability

Two adult male baboons are introduced to the same $50$ ft. square cage.  Male A looks at Male B for a total of $5$ hours in the first ($24$ hour) day, and Male B looks at Male A for a total of $3$ hours in the same first day.  If the two baboons behave independently of each other, what is the probability that they will look at each other at the same time (at least once) on that first day?

My thinking: I think this can be solved geometrically, but I am having trouble interpreting it. Can I interpret it to $0 < B < 5$ and $0 < A < 3$ and $A-B > 0$?

Another solution I had for this question is that: Two baboons only look together if A's $5$ hour is happening within the $3$ hours of B looking at A. So the probability would be $\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{24}=\frac{1}{8}$? I think it is wrong though.

Comment: I guess the answer to your question depends on the length of the timeslots you assume. Have you tried to discretisize the problem with different timeslots (eg. 1min vs 1h)?

Comment: the problem is that we cannot assume this 3 hours or 5 hours happen continuously, it may not be a time chunk of a total 3 hours or a time chunk of a total 5 hours. Instead, it may be a lot of secs or mins accumulating to 3 hours or 5 hours. Therefore, it seems quite hard to discretisize the problem. :)

Comment: I partly agree. So far there isn't a mathematical model you were able to map your problem on. If you discretisize the problem (say 1h time slots) the mathematical model is the same, as if the baboons were drawing numbered balls (24) from a box, A draws 5, puts them back, B draws 3, probability they drew at least 1 identical ball. Let's call it the (24,5,3,1) problem. If (n*24,n*5,n*3,1) has a limit for n to inf, your problem should be solved, otherwise it's not well definied

Comment: I kind of get what you are saying. I was trying to think of something calculus-ish to solve the problem. Does it ring a bell for you?

Comment: Not really. Continuously you'd have to model the "look at's" as functions a,b: [0, 24]->{0,1} and I'm not sure if there is something like a utilizable event space for this. But a times b should be integrable! Therefore if you rephrase your problem to A and B look at each other for at least x hours then you'd have to solve lim(n ->inf) (n*24, n*5,n*3, n*x) instead of ...,1), which is more likely to converge.

Comment: I'm completely lost. So should I just solve it discretely? Try to find an hour they stare at each other?

Comment: Yes, try 1h timeslot were they look at each other in one slot, try 0,01h timeslots were they look at each other in 100 slots, ... and try to extract a limit for n -> inf, where you have 1/n h timeslots where they look at each other in n slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Decomposing the day into $n$ equal timeslots with $n$ large and assuming each animal chooses randomly uniformly and independently the necessary number of timeslots, one gets a probability of no eye contact approximately equal to $\mathrm e^{-n/10}.$

Let $u=5/24$ and $v=8/24$, then Male A looks at Male B during $a$ timeslots, with $a=un$, and Male B looks at Male A during $b$ timeslots, with $b=vn$. Fix the $a$ timeslots used by Male A. No eye contact happens if Male B uses $b$ distinct timeslots taken from the $n-a$ remaining "free" timeslots. Consider that Male B chooses his $b$ timeslots sequentially. The first timeslot Male B chooses is free with probability $(n-a)/n$. Conditionally on this, the second timeslot Male B chooses is free with probability $(n-a-1)/(n-1)$, and so on until timeslot number $b$, which is free with conditional probability $(n-a-b+1)/(n-b+1)$. Thus, the exact probability of no eye contact is $$p=\prod_{i=0}^{b-1}\frac{n-a-i}{n-i}=\frac{(n-a)!\,(n-b)!}{n!\,(n-a-b)!}.$$ When $u$ and $v$ are fixed and $n\to\infty$ with $a=un$ and $b=vn$, $$\frac{\log p}n\to-\theta=(1-u)\log(1-u)+(1-v)\log(1-v)-(1-u-v)\log(1-u-v),$$ hence one can approximate $p$ as $$p\approx\mathrm e^{-\theta n}.$$
If $u=5/24$ and $v=8/24$, $\theta\approx.09768249$. For a decomposition into hours, $n=24$ hence $p\approx9.6\%$. For a decomposition into minutes, $n=1440$ hence $p\approx10^{-61}$. 
For a decomposition into seconds, $n=86,400$ hence $p\approx10^{-3665}$.

---

Having said that (which solves the problem as interpreted by the OP), my impression is that the real question assumes some continuous periods of 5 hours, respectively 3 hours, in the day, and asks for the probability of no eye contact, that is, that the time intervals corresponding to these periods do not intersect.

This happens if and only if the midpoints $X$ and $Y$ of the intervals are at distance more than $4$, $X$ being uniform on $(2.5,21,5)$ and $Y$ uniform on $(1.5,22.5)$. Equivalently, one can consider $X$ uniform on $(0,19)$ and $Y$ uniform on $(0,21)$. Then $p$ is the normalized sum of the area of the two triangles $X\gt Y+4$ and $Y\gt X+4$, that is, $$p=\frac{\frac1217^2+\frac1215^2}{19\cdot21}=\frac{257}{399}\approx64\%.$$

Comment: it's by so far the cleanest formula!!!

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter Sorry but this answer assumes nothing of the sort (and I find your assertive tone a bit strange).

Comment: @Did You're right. Those answers can't be compared the way I did (please see the discussion in Davids answer). Although I still think that the problem is best modelled with a hypergeometric distribution I apologize if my tone was not appropriate

Comment: If your answer is right, mine is wrong (for minute slots I get a probability of 2.11e-18%). You could reduce my conviction by showing were I went wrong (no passive aggressiveness included)

Answer (score 0):

Using $1$ second timeslots and assuming a $24$ hour day which has $86,400$ seconds in it and only considering those seconds, the chances of A not looking at B during any random $1$ second interval is $19$ / $24$.  The chances of B not looking at A during any random $1$ second interval is $21$ / $24$.  So for them to not see each other in any random of the $86,400$ seconds we let x = $19 / 24 * 21/24$ which is $133/192$ or about $69.27$%. We then take $x^{86,400}$ which is the chance that they will not see each other in all $86,400$ seconds.  This answer however is virtually $0$.  Therefore it is almost certain that they will look at each other at least once during the conditions of this problem.

Comment: It's not clear how you got 73,54%. How did you calculate that?

Comment: The approach to give every second the same probability is not valid, since the probabilities for the respective timeslots are dependant. It's like wanting to have all number from 1 to six once, and therefore rolling a d6 six times. For big numbers it might work to get rather close to x, but with $x^{86,400}$ the error made will accumulate rather fast

Comment: Maybe the following is easier to understand: It's like a box with balls, in your case you put the balls back, in case of the problem they remain outside. In the first case the draws are independant, in the problems case not. If A already looked at be for the first 2h the probabilities shift dramatically

Comment: A and B can look at each other during any of the $86,400$ seconds during the day independently of each other so why wouldn't each second be equally likely to be chosen by either? For example, A could look up at B for $1$ second then look away, wait a few more seconds, then repeat. B could do something similar. Assuming this, eventually they would have to see each other. The chances of them not are virtually $0$. Also, why would A look at B for the first $2$ hours? Maybe buffoon A and/or bassoon B has/have ADD and doesn't/don't stay interested in anything for more than a few seconds at a time.

Comment: Things we are not considering but maybe should are sleep times of A and B and whether they overlap or not but the OP didn't mention anything about that so we can assume they are up 24/7.  However in reality, baboons sleep maybe 10 hours in a 24 hour period.

Comment: If you have an ape looking at the other with a probability of 1/8 each second you don't have him to end up with 3h looking, but only with an expectation value of 3h. "Also, why would A look at B for the first 2 hours?" That was just an example to show you how the probability of the separate seconds depend on each other. If you don't understand this example, don't mind, skip it. Go back to the balls in the box example, with and without laying back and try to get the transfer to this problem.

Comment: And yes, 24/7 was always assumed, but has nothing to do with my critcs

Comment: The OP specifically stated that A and B behave independently (I assume that means of each other).  In reality this is a silly question because immediately upon sharing the same cage, they would likely check each other out or even fight so how could they do that without looking at each other?

Comment: "The OP specifically stated that A and B behave independently". That's right and I didn't say anything against that. Furthermore will I not discuss if the assumed model fits reality.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be gone in 5min, and I must assume this will take longer. please have a look in the hypergeometric distribution, and what it is used for. CU

Comment: Despite the problem that you are doing a discrete math for a continuous problem, using the same method, you can also get the chance of seeing each other converges to zero and not seeing thus becoming 1.

Comment: Continuous is just discrete with very small granularity.  That is, busted up into very many small pieces, slices, time slices...  Actually you can approximate things very well using discrete math when an exact value is not needed.  For example, $2$ cups of the same height but one is constant diameter of $4$ inches and the other tapers smoothly from $3$ to $5$ inches with a $4$ inch center diameter.  Which one can hold more volume?  You don't need to know calculus for this. Just take $2$ cross sections and you will see that ($3^2$ + $5^2$) > ($4^2$ + $4^2$) so the tapered cup can hold more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming timeslots (eg. of one hour) then the problem can be modeled with the hypergeometric distribution (5 good cases, 24 cases in total, 3 tries). A computation in  python suggests a probability of 47% for not seeing each other:

```
>>>from scipy.stats import hypergeom
>>>hypergeom.cdf(0,24,5,3)
0.47875494071146002 ....
>>>hypergeom.cdf(0,240,50,30)
0.0005341306533842992
>>>hypergeom.cdf(0,2400,500,300)
1.591211147566946e-33
```

Using timeslots of 1/10h and 1/100h the probability of not seeing each other vanishes rapidely (0,05% , 0%), one may assume that for the a neglegible length of the timeslots the chance of seeing each other is 1.

Comment: The possible problem for this is that if you run the case another way around, it will converge to zero as well. You can use the same method to get the chance of seeing as 0 and not seeing as 1. Does what I worry make sense to you?

Comment: The calculation above the probability for not seeing each other (number of timeslots they see each other == 0 or sum(s == 0)). For the other way round you need (number of timeslots they see each other > 0 or sum(s > 0)), which converges to 1.

Answer (score -3):

When I revisit this question:

Let event A be that the male baboon A looking at the male baboon B. P(A)=5/24

Let event B be that the male baboon B looking at the male baboon A. P(B)=3/24

So P(A and B)=5/24*3/24=5/192

Comment: That is not correct.  Just think about what that means.  You are saying that $2$ baboons that combined, look at the other baboon for a total of $8$ hours in a $24$ hour day will only have about a $2.6$% chance of seeing each other during that $24$ hour period.  That is WAY off!

Comment: Well. It is what it appears. You can't really interpret this into a reality sense. I have to acknowledge that my solution is the most naive one. But when you really think about it, applying complex mathematical models in it, the problem simply gets way complicated and probably unsolvable. I googled some articles on mutual gaze: there are errors as long as you get into this deeper than the naive sense. Also, I have to admit that this is not the right way to counter this kind of problems....but well, it is the cleanest one.

Comment: You could run a simulation to convince yourself that the probability is almost certain (almost $1.0$) that they will see each other.  Imagine if you had $2$ flashing lights so that they flash on for exactly $1$ second.  Light A would flash $18,000$ times (the # of seconds in $5$ hours) and light B would flash $10,800$ times (the # of seconds in $3$ hours).  Now think about the chances of both of those lights flashing at the same time at least once.  It is almost a $100$% probability because how can those random flashing lights avoid each other each and every time if they are independent?

Comment: you can also run a simulation to get the probability as zero! The probability for flashing at the same time or not the same time at the given time interval (1s) are both smaller than one! And you power the probability with that huge number of seconds, they both converge to zero! You can only say who gets zero first!

Comment: My $x^{86,400}$ converges to $0$ because that is the probability that they will NOT see each other at all so therefore the complement converges to $1$ which is an almost certainty they will see each other.

Comment: yes. Do a calculation on the probability that they will see each other! It converges to zero as well! Let x be the chance they see each other at any particular given second. Tell me what's your result?

Comment: That is what I did.  It converges to $1$.  For this type of problem, you compute the complement and then subtract that from $1$.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase it. You got 1 because the complement converges to 0. Now I'm asking you to treat the seeing each other as the complement part and use the same method.

Comment: My chat doesn't seem to work.  Think of a simpler example to help illustrate the concept of complements and when to use them.  What is the chance of rolling a $6$ on a fair die at least once in exactly $10$ rolls?  The easy way is to compute the complement which is the chance of not rolling ANY $6$s so that is simply ($5/6)^{10}$ = about $16$% so the complement would be about $84$% chance of getting at least one $6$ in $10$ rolls.  Using your "logic", how would you compute the chance of getting at least one $6$ using any other method?  There is a $1/6$th chance on the first roll.  Then what?

Comment: Since there is a $1/6$th chance each roll, we already know the correct answer is AT LEAST $1/6$ since we cannot do worse with more than $1$ roll to get at least one $6$ so do you see why you "converges to $0$" logic is highly flawed in the "ape" question?  Those type of problems where it is asked for "at least once" are a clear sign that you should probably use the complement method of finding NONE, then subtract that answer from $1$. Obviously you cannot say $(1/6)^{10}$ is the probability of getting at least one $6$ and $1/6$ + $1/6$ ... $10$ times wont work either since that is $10/6$.