# How to find probability that depends on time?

Tags: probability

**To moderators: feel free to change title "to more specific", because I can't do this, I have no idea what theory I should use here. I tried to describe the problem as detailed as possible with good example.**

We have 4 websites and we know, that only 20% of visitors on website #1 (w1) like rock music. For website #2 (w2) - only 30% of visitors like rock music. For w3 - 70%, w4 - 90%:

```
Website | P(likes rock music)
-----------------------------
w1      | 0.2
w2      | 0.3
w3      | 0.7
w4      | 0.9
```

We assume, that if a user spends more time on websites that visited mostly by users, who like rock music, this user likes rock music too.

User #1 (u1) spent 10 minutes on w1, 15 minutes on w2, but only 1 minute on w3 and 1 minute on w4. So, looks like he doesn't like rock music because he doesn't spend much time on rock-oriented websites w3 and w4.

```
User | Website | Spent time
-----------------------------
u1   | w1      | 10
u1   | w2      | 15
u1   | w3      | 1
u1   | w4      | 1
```

But user #2 (u2) spent about the same time on both websites:

```
User | Website | Spent time
-----------------------------
u2   | w1      | 5
u2   | w2      | 6
u2   | w3      | 4
u2   | w4      | 3
```

What probability that u1 and u2 like rock music?

Comment: Duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570279/how-to-find-probability-that-depends-on-other-probability. Try editing the other post instead.

Comment: @P.Quinton it's closed with "add details and clarify the problem you’re solving". I have detailed example. Can you help me, what else I can do?

Comment: You should rephrase the first post.

Comment: @P.Quinton can you be a little bit more specific, what should I rephrase? I used this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986997/time-based-probability-question?rq=1 as example.

Comment: @YuiToCheng, what do you mean? There is no answer.